# Hibernate - Redis: Second Level Cache is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, redis

I have an issue related to hibernate level 2 cache. It works with getById method, but not other method:

This is my code:

> jpa:
> database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
> database: MYSQL
> show-sql: true
> properties:
> hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
> hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
> hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
> hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: true
> hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.mycompany.myapp.config.CustomRegionFactory
> hibernate.generate_statistics: true
> hibernate.cache.region_prefix: hibernate
> hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries: true

```
@Configuration @EnableCaching public class CacheConfiguration {
@Bean
public javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
    MutableConfiguration<Object, Object> jcacheConfig = new MutableConfiguration<>();
    Config config = new Config();
    config.useSingleServer().setAddress(jHipsterProperties.getCache().getRedis().getServer());
    jcacheConfig.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
    jcacheConfig.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, jHipsterProperties.getCache().getRedis().getExpiration())));
    return RedissonConfiguration.fromInstance(Redisson.create(config), jcacheConfig);
}

@Bean
public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(javax.cache.CacheManager cm) {
    return hibernateProperties -> hibernateProperties.put(ConfigSettings.CACHE_MANAGER, cm);
}

@Bean
public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer(javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration) {
    return cm -> {
        createCache(cm, com.mycompany.myapp.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE, jcacheConfiguration);
        createCache(cm, com.mycompany.myapp.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE, jcacheConfiguration);
        createCache(cm, com.mycompany.myapp.domain.User.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
        createCache(cm, com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Authority.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
        createCache(cm, com.mycompany.myapp.domain.User.class.getName() + ".authorities", jcacheConfiguration);
        createCache(cm, com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Company.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
        // jhipster-needle-redis-add-entry
    };
}

private void createCache(javax.cache.CacheManager cm, String cacheName, javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration) {
    javax.cache.Cache<Object, Object> cache = cm.getCache(cacheName);
    if (cache != null) {
        cm.destroyCache(cacheName);
    }
    cm.createCache(cacheName, jcacheConfiguration);
} }
```

public class CustomRegionFactory extends RedissonRegionFactory {

```
@Override
protected RedissonClient createRedissonClient(Map properties) {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:6379").setRetryInterval(1500)
        .setRetryAttempts(3).setConnectTimeout(10000)
        .setClientName("client1");

    return Redisson.create(config);
}
```

}

Entity:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.domain;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * A Company.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Company name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Company)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id != null && id.equals(((Company) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Hey, did you finally find an answser to your problem ?